# Scraping web Football Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the data from a website "https://www.maxifoot.fr/classement-buteur-europe-annee-civile-2021.htm"

I tried to extract these data on Python but I couldn't make it. I would like to create a table on Python with thoses data and the same fields. Can someone try to help me  with the script of the data extraction using pandas, beautifulsoup... ?

I already tried this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.maxifoot.fr/classement-buteur-europe-annee-civile-2021.htm'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
for i in soup.find_all("tr"):
    print(i.find_all("td"))
    print ("")
    colonnes = ["Nom","Equipe","Buts","Matchs joués"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colonnes)
df

for i in soup.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    href = i.find_all("td")
    df = df.append({'Nom': href}, ignore_index=True)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Good answers require good questions, please help make your problem understandable to all by improving your question. In general, existing code and expected result should be presented as text.  Read also --> How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: This is what I tried ! (in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an much simpler way to grab the data and put it in a dataframe - Use `pandas.read_html` and make your adjustments if needed with pandas.

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.maxifoot.fr/classement-buteur-europe-annee-civile-2021.htm', match = 'min/but*')[1]

df['href'] = df["Joueur"].apply(lambda x: 'https://www.maxifoot.fr'+soup.select_one(f'a:-soup-contains("{x}")')['href'])
```

If you like to solve it with BeautifulSoup, there are some adjustments you have to do:

```
...
data = []
for row in soup.select('.butd1 tr')[1:]:
    strings = list(row.stripped_strings)
    strings[3:5] = [''.join(strings[3:5])]
    strings[6:8] = [''.join(strings[6:8])]
    a = 'https://www.maxifoot.fr'+row.a['href']
    strings.append(a)
    data.append(strings)
colonnes = ['Pos','Nom','Equipe','Buts','dontchamp.','Matchs joués','min/but*','href']
pd.DataFrame(data,columns = colonnes)
```

#### Output

| Pos | Nom | Equipe | Buts | dontchamp. | Matchs joués | min/but* | href |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | R. LEWANDOWSKI | Bayern Munich | 58 (11 p.) | 43 | 47 (1,23 b/m) | 68' | https://www.maxifoot.fr/joueur/robert-lewandowski-13191.htm |
| 2. | E. HAALAND | Borussia Dortmund | 43 (6 p.) | 30 | 43 (1,00 b/m) | 85' | https://www.maxifoot.fr/joueur/erling-haland-190157.htm |
| . | K. MBAPPÉ | Paris SG | 43 (7 p.) | 24 | 53 (0,81 b/m) | 104' | https://www.maxifoot.fr/joueur/kylian-mbappe-lottin-183802.htm |
| 4. | K. BENZEMA | Real Madrid | 38 (3 p.) | 30 | 50 (0,76 b/m) | 109' | https://www.maxifoot.fr/joueur/karim-benzema-10476.htm |
| 5. | MOHAMED SALAH | Liverpool | 37 (4 p.) | 24 | 53 (0,70 b/m) | 122' | https://www.maxifoot.fr/joueur/mohamed-salah-59580.htm |

...

Comment: All right however, when I try this script I have an error :

Comment: SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)

...
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)

Comment: Note sure why this happens on your site, hope all libraries are up to date - However, added also the BeautifulSoup approache, take a look .